# CSS Section Align

Tags: html, css, wordpress

URL: https://tktsmallorca.com/

[image]

I am trying to use css to make the stars align vertically to the bottom of the section. The ID of the stars section is starsbot

I have tried

```
.starsbot{
    vertical-align: bottom !important;
}
```

This did not work.

The site is made in **wordpress with elementor.** The section has a content align setting but this makes the image, and title drop down. I am looking  to override this and have only the stars align to the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
.elementor-column-wrap, .elementor-widget-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.starsbot {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much for the help.